# Php-script create file not from user www-data

Tags: php, apache, permissions, debian

My name lebnik, and information about me:

```
# id lebnik
uid=1000(lebnik) gid=1000(lebnik) groups=1000(lebnik),24(cdrom),25(floppy),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev)
```

My apache run php-scripts from user www-data, check this:

```
root@debian /etc/apache2 # grep -R "APACHE_RUN_USER=" .
./envvars:export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
```

Information about user www-data:

```
# id www-data
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
```

I create php-script file.php:

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

echo `whoami`;

$file = __FILE__.'.tmp';

file_put_contents($file, 'Hi');

echo file_get_contents($file)."\n";

$dirname = dirname(__FILE__);

echo `ls -la $dirname`;
?>
```

Next, I try call my script with Apache:

```
# curl http://starsite.l/test/file.php
www-data
Hi
total 16
drwxrwxrwx 1 lebnik www-data 4096 Oct 18 00:49 .
drwxrwxr-x 1 lebnik www-data 4096 Oct 18 00:36 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lebnik www-data  225 Oct 18 00:46 file.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 lebnik www-data    2 Oct 18 00:49 file.php.tmp
```

You see this? PHP create file **file.php.tmp** from user **lebnik**. Whats wrong in my configurations?

Comment: This behavior is very strange. What OS do you use?

Comment: You are most likely having a shared hosting account. Your apache setup uses [suexec](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/suexec.html) (through Fast-CGI or similar) to run your PHP scripts as the file's owner (not as apache) for security reasons. When you call `whoami` command external to your PHP script, whoami command is run as the apache user `www-data`.

Comment: You probably can change some configuration file to make even external commands to run as your user account.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I mount the folder in VirtualBox from the wrong user:

```
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=33 starsite.l /var/www/starsite.l
```

Correct mounting:

```
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=33,gid=33 starsite.l /var/www/starsite.l
```